# Add UIPageControl to navigationbar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I have a `TableViewController` as the root controller of a `NavigationController`.

I want to add a page indicator to the navigationbar.

In viewDidLoad in my `TableViewController` class i added following code:

```
let navBarsize = navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.size
let origin = CGPointMake(navBarsize.width/2, navBarsize.height/2)

let pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, 0, 0))
pageControl.numberOfPages = 2
pageControl.currentPage = 1

navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(pageControl)
```

But there is no UIPageControl showing in my navigationbar.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify size of UIPageController.

```
let pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, 100, 20))
```

shows the UIPageController up.